# Codeigniter run mysql query and echo number of returned rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
<?=$this->db->count_all_results('users')?>
```

Hi, I am stuck on something. How can run a query like the below count and echo all of the returned rows? I am currently using the above statement but I need this improvement.

```
<?php $aa = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE itemNumber = 1");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use num_rows() method

```
<?php
 $aa = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE itemNumber = 1");
echo $aa->num_rows();

?>
```

Comment: thanks man. I couldn't seem to figure out how to do it on an active record object. i new how to do it in native php though lol

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->query("SELECT u.*, COUNT(u_all.*) FROM users u, users u_all WHERE u.itemNumber = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$numRows = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE itemNumber = 1");
```